# LWJGL Texture not stretching to Quads

Tags: java, opengl, 2d, lwjgl

I have been trying for hours to get a Texture in LWJGL to stretch to a quad.

Here is the code I am using for the quad:

```
private static void renderLoad() {
    glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    texture.bind();

    glPushMatrix();{
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    {
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex2f(0, 0); //Upper-left

        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex2f(Display.getWidth(), 0); //Upper-right

        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex2f(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight()); //Bottom-right

        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2f(0, Display.getHeight()); //Bottom-left
    }
    glEnd();
    }glPopMatrix();
}
```

This is what the display looks like when I run it:
http://gyazo.com/376ddb0979c55226d2f63c26215a1e12

I am trying to make the image expand to the size of the window.  The Quad is at the size of the window, but the texture seems to not stretch.

Here is what it looks like if I do not use a texture and I simple make the quad a color:
http://gyazo.com/65f21fe3efa2d3948de69b55d5c85424

If it helps here is my main loop:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glViewport(0, 0, displaySizeX, displaySizeY);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0, displaySizeX, 0, displaySizeY, 1, -1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        texture = loadLoadingImage();

        //This is the main loop for the game.
        while(!Display.isCloseRequested()){
            delta = getDelta();
            updateFPS();
            if(Display.wasResized()){
                displaySizeX = Display.getWidth();
                displaySizeY = Display.getHeight();
                glViewport(0, 0, displaySizeX, displaySizeY);
                glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
                glLoadIdentity();
                glOrtho(0, displaySizeX, 0, displaySizeY, -1, 1);
            }
            render();
            checkInput();
            Display.update();
            Display.sync(sync);
        }

        cleanUp();
        return true;
```

How do I make the image stretch to the quad?

Comment: You don't set the matrix mode back to `GL_MODELVIEW` in your display resize code. Not sure if that is causing the issue though.

Comment: I tried fixing and removing that and it did nothing.  Even without changing the display it still does not stretch the image.

Comment: What are you using to load the texture? It looks like it might be one of those toolkits that round up the texture size to the next power of two while loading.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I am using slick-utitls.  Anyways I solved the problem.  It was the image.  I read somewhere that the image/texture had to be able to be divided by 2 and it had to be an exponent of two.  I changed my image size to 1024 and now it works great!

Comment: That's really just a limitation of the library you are using for loading the image. The restriction that OpenGL textures need to have sizes that are a power of two was lifted a long time ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void stretch() {
        Color.white.bind();
        texture.bind

        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(100,100);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(100+texture.getTextureWidth(),100);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(100+texture.getTextureWidth(),100+character.getTextureHeight());
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(100,100+texture.getTextureHeight());

        GL11.glEnd(); // all the 0's were originally 100 but it was off centered
    }

texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG",ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("res/texture.png"));
```

Try using this. This is usually how I do this.

Comment: Okay that did not work.  The image was now upside down and a mirror image.  It also did not stretch.

Comment: Well. You will need to take your image and make it large either via an online tool or an application so that it is large enough for your screen. If the screen is 800 x 600 for example make the image 800+600 or you can also just go next to where it says texture.getTextureWidth() and change it to texture.getTextureWidth() + differenceneeded

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something is modifying the texture matrix.  You could try adding a

```
glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
glLoadIdentity();
```

to see if that affects anything.

Comment: I changed it to that and it still does not stretch.  Could it be that I am using JPG?